# Symfony + API Platform: Error 500 on all post requests (appeared suddenly)

Tags: symfony, runtime-error, api-platform.com

I'm currently working on an API using Symfony and API_Platform.

Everything is going great (POST requests are working), but suddendly i can't make any POST request (even using EasyAdmin bundle).

Im getting this logs :

```
2019-05-23T13:51:05+00:00 [critical] Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found
[Thu May 23 15:51:05 2019] 127.0.0.1:54351 [500]: /api/authors - Class 'Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client' not found in D:\projects\hp-api-2\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Client.php on line 31
2019-05-23T13:51:05+00:00 [critical] Fatal Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client' not found
```

I tried to require both bundles but it did not fix my errors.

I created another API Project, worked on it for 2 days, and the same error appeared again for no reason.

I'm totally lost about this one.

I'm using Wamp for PHP/MySQL. But i dont think it's the problem since it was working fine before.

Here are my dependencies:

```
"require": {
        "php": "~7.2.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "api-platform/api-pack": "^1.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.0",
        "easycorp/easyadmin-bundle": "^2.1",
        "symfony/apache-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/console": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.1",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.2.*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.11",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.2.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "^1.0",
        "symfony/web-server-bundle": "4.2.*"
    }
```

When I require symfony/browser-kit --dev, I get this:

```
2019-05-23T13:57:34+00:00 [critical] Class 'GuzzleHttp\Client' not found
2019-05-23T13:57:35+00:00 [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "Client" from namespace "GuzzleHttp".
Did you forget a "use" statement for e.g. "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client", "Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client" or "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client"?" at D:\projects\hp-api-2\var\cache\dev\ContainerDsBBqcY\getApiPlatform_Doctrine_Listener_HttpCache_PurgeService.php line 13
```

And if I require guzzlehttp/guzzle --dev I get this :

```
2019-05-23T14:01:32+00:00 [critical] Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\EnvNotFoundException: "Environment variable not found: "VARNISH_URL"." at D:\projects\hp-api-2\vendor\symfony\dependency-injection\EnvVarProcessor.php line 96
```

I didnt configure cache system at all, it's the default settings.

If you need any more informations, feel free to ask.

Please excuse me for English mistakes, if I did any.

Thank you.

Antoine

EDIT: I tried to not use wamp for my php/mysql and now when I make a post request i have some error message from Symfony (i didnt have one before):

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException:
Error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client' not found in D:\projects\hp-api-2\vendor\symfony\http-kernel\Client.php:31
Stack trace:
#0 D:\projects\hp-api-2\vendor\symfony\debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php(174): require_once()
#1 D:\projects\hp-api-2\vendor\symfony\debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php(136): Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->convertFileToClass('D:\\projects\\hp-...', 'D:\\projects\\hp-...', 'Symfony\\Compone...')
#2 D:\projects\hp-api-2\vendor\symfony\debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php(118): Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->findClassInPath('D:\\projects\\hp-...', 'Client', 'Symfony\\Compone...')
#3 D:\projects\hp-api-2\vendor\symfony\debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler.php(62): Symfony\Component\Debug\FatalErrorHandler\ClassNotFoundFatalErrorHandler->getClassCandidates('Client')
#4 D:\projects\hp-api-2\vendor\s

  at vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Client.php:31
```

EDIT 2: I "fixed" my problem by requiring both bundles + disabling varnish urls

```
api_platform:
    version: 0.0.1

    mapping:
        # paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity']
        paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/config/api_platform/resources'] 

    http_cache:
        invalidation:
            enabled: true
            # varnish_urls: ['%env(VARNISH_URL)%'] ## this problem still needs to be fixed
        max_age: 0
        shared_max_age: 3600
        vary: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        public: true
```

Comment: Did you try `$ composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: @MohamedRadhiGuennichi i just tried it and i still got the errors

Answer (score 0):

I've just fixed by adding guzzle dependency:

```
composer req guzzlehttp/guzzle
```